# getContentLength returns -1 when trying to get XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android programming and would like to get some help on why `getContentLength()` returns `-1` when I try to get the XML data.

The XML url is

```
String url = "http://www.systembolaget.se/api/assortment/products/xml";
```

---

```
  int count;
                try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lengthOfFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 10240);
                File fileDir = getFileFolder(AndroAsync.this);
                File file = new File (fileDir, "systembolaget.xml");
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);


                byte data[] = new byte[4096];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/ lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                input.close();
```

All help is much appreciated
Thank you! :)

Comment: Documentation says it returns "`-1` if the field is not set or cannot be represented as an int", so that's the reason

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation but I don't get what they mean by that it cannot be represented as an int.

Comment: It can't be represented as an int if it is too large for an int, but it's more probable that it just isn't set at all.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That server isn't sending a content-length, and the reason is that it is using chunked transfer-encoding.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=78517
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
ETag: "bb83f8d6-d015-4df5-a8f6-e37248d8a812"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Cached: True
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 05:11:22 GMT
X-Cnection: close
Set-Cookie: lbsession=rd10o00000000000000000000ffff91fbfd15o80; path=/
X-Server: 21
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Okay! So do you know if there's a different way of implementing what I want? I wanted to know content-length because I want to use a ProgressDialog with a progress bar.